# Flutter: buttons that can't both be toggle on

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm having trouble making the UI I intended. I want to make two buttons be next to each other horizontally, when one of the buttons is pressed the other is unpressed (like toggle).

```
ElevatedButton(
                style: ButtonStyle(
                  foregroundColor: getColor(Colors.green, Colors.white),
                  backgroundColor: getColor(Colors.white, Colors.green),
                  side: getBorder(Colors.green, Colors.white),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  isSafe = true;
                  setState(() {
                    safetyMessage = 'Currently Safe: $isSafe';
                  });
                },
                child: const Text('Yes'),
              ),
```

this is one of the buttons, there is an identical button for "no".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to implement the functionality directly you could use a [ChoiceChip Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ChoiceChip-class.html) or a [SegmentedButton Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SegmentedButton-class.html) since they both make use of the functionality you are wanting directly.